# View history on SE questions

Tags: support, user-accounts, hidden-features

I don't know whether this has been asked before, but is it possible to access the history of questions viewed by a user while logged in on SE sites? I have noticed there is a viewed counter if that helps. So how can I view my SE history?

Comment: I think someone last asked this was 3 years ago. Features might have changed by then.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no history of what questions or pages a user has viewed, not even for yourself. A user's browsing history is not valuable information that needs to be displayed to anyone else, and for yourself, well you can just look through your browser history if you don't clear it out on a regular basis.

As far as the views counter, it doesn't even keep track of each user who viewed the question for more than a short amount of time (approximately 15 minutes if I remember correctly). It's just a denormalized number stored in a database field. Stack Exchange does keep logs of all the hits that come in, but your actual browsing history on the site is not in any way tracked in the database, in any form that is easily accessible to be displayed back to you.

You can view all the activity that *is* tracked from your account by visiting the activity tab in your profile. This is generally limited to anything you'd submit or post to the site that is publicly displayed to other users, though.